# Pass value from controller to another in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller

I have an ASP.net web application in C# in which an user can connect to watch data (from a database stored locally in my app).

In the Index.cshtml page, when the user enters his credentials and then press the connection button, it will launch the httppost function, with the username and password of the user as arguments.
At this moment, my function will check if these credentials match to a username/password pair in my database, in the table "User_connection". If yes, it will redirect the user to another page (EmbedReport.cshtml), in which the user will see his personal data. I use the httpget function of EmbedReport to past the data from my database to my View.
My "User_Connection" table has 3 main columns, which are username and password, to be able to connect, and Contact_name, which I will use to filter the data.
The data I will display in my web app is from another table. 
But in order to filter the data, so the user see only his own data, I need to past the Contact_name value, from my "User_Connection" table, from my httppost (Index) function to the httpget (EmbedReport) function.
 Is it possible to do that when the redirect method occurs? Or, if not, is there another way to do that?

My Index.cshtml :

```
<form method="post" , enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input required id="my_pseudo" name="my_pseudo" v-model="pseudo" placeholder="Username" />
            <input required id="my_password" name="my_password" type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="password" />

            <Button id="test_click" Text="Connexion">Connection</Button>

        </form>
```

My httpget function :

```
public ActionResult EmbedReport()
        {

            List<Dashboard___Veins_Data___By_Institution> my_list = fct_BO.Class1.My_function("my_user");
            // It's at this moment that the filter is applied, so I want that, instead of "my_user", I can put a variable which is the "Contact_name" of the user currently connected.
            ViewBag.Message = my_list;


            return View();
        }
```

My httppost function

```
public ActionResult Index(string my_pseudo, string my_password)
        {
            
            
            
            //It's not good for the moment, but it's here that I want to see if "my_pseudo" and "my_password" match a line of my table "User_connection". If yes, the redirect method occurs ->

            // if (...)
                  Response.Redirect("~/Home/EmbedReport");

            // If not, then the user will receive an error message.
            // else
            //    Response.Write("<script>alert('Login or password incorrect')</script>");

            return View();
            
        }
```

I didn't finish this function, because my table "User_connection" is not finished for the moment.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could we have some code

Comment: Yes, I just edited my first post and added my code.

Comment: Anyone got an idea?